# http client in windows 8 app

Tags: json, web-services, windows-8, windows-8.1

i made an app in windows phone successfully & now i want to make it for windows 8 store app but i stuck on a point where i want to my web service in store app.

I use webclient in WP but i don't know anything about how to access web service in Windows 8 store app. My web service return data in json format  i deserialize & store in a variable in WP & i use post method . but how it would be done in Windows 8 store app.
what would i use for windows 8 in place of Webclient.

i post my windows phone code

```
    private void PostData()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(my web service url);
        string data = "device_id=" + val + "&quiz_type=all";
          WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, data);
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadComplete;
    }
    public void wc_UploadComplete(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {         
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
     }
```

You see that i store all the data in rootObject.
How these thing can be done in windows 8 app?

Answer (score 1):

1st Method: Parsing and Reusing JSON Objects

Step1: Go to Json2Csharp site and paste either your entire JSON string or URL to the JSON and click on Generate button. This creates all the required classes for your JSON response.
For example, this JSON dataset:

```
{"MyBlogList":[{"ID":9,"TYPE":"WindowsPhone","TITLE":"XYZ","PRICE":"0","IMAGE":"Post1.jpg"}],"success":3}
The generated class object is:



public class MyBlogList
 {
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string TYPE { get; set; }
 public string TITLE { get; set; }
 public string PRICE { get; set; }
 public string IMAGE { get; set; }
 }
 public class RootObject
 {
 public List<MyBlogList> MyBlogList { get; set; }
 public int success { get; set; }
 }
```

Now place this class somewhere in your project, so that it will be available in the required locations.

Step 2: (i.e. assuming that you get your JSON from a web service), Make a web request to get the JSON response
You will have to use the WebClient class as well as enabling the DownloadStringCompleted Event handler which returns the response to be manipulated.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(http://somedomain.com/xyz/myjson.aspx)); 
And then in the response handler, use the following code to parse the data and convert into classes:

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
 var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result); 
 foreach (var blog in rootObject.MyBlogList) 
 { 
 Console.WriteLine(blog.TITLE);
 } 
 }
```

2nd Method: One Time JSON Parse

Here as your requirement is one time parsing and one time usage, instead of storing them in unnecessary classes, we just wisely parse the data and get the task done.

Consider the exact same sample JSON dataset provided above, and we want to get the blog title so here is the code snippet for that:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
JArray jarr = (JArray)obj["MyBlogList"];
string blogTitle = (string)jarr[0]["TITLE"]; //To get the title of the blog 
 or
foreach(var item in jarr) 
 Console.WriteLine(item["TITLE"]); //Gets the title of each book in the list
```

There you go, you can play with the response and bind the data with the UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781239.aspx).

```
private async Task UploadData()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; WIndows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        string data = "device_id=" + val + "&quiz_type=all";
        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("payloadData", data)
        });

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(my web service url), content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }

        // This is your responce data.
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. How post method is used in this code?Look i have 77 question on service but when i pass device id & quiz type, the no. of question is raised as device id is stored in database via web service. For this post method is used. how do i get post method on this...?

Comment: hey i won the half phase but my device-id is not attached with my web service due to this i am not getting all the question. please help me on this....